# How to put image in front of check box in android ..?

Tags: android, checkbox

How to put image and check box in same line in android like this iamge [image] can image view use for this ? 
 Thanks.

Comment: this is a good question, i would like to know that number of  checkbox are dynamic or static?

Comment: is it conveneant to display image after text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linear Layout for each row and put all of them in to this also use `android:layout_toRightOf` for each widget like checkbox, Textview  Use Like This

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/layout1">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/im1"/>
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ck1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/im1"/>
<TextView android:text="hi" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ck1"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/layout2" android:layout_below="@id/layout1">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/im2"/>
<CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ck1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/im2"/>
<TextView android:text="hello" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ck2"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is quite simple.

Use ralative layout(Very important). Place your image where you want it(you can align it w.r.t the parent layout) and then use 'to right of' option in your xml to align the checkbox next to the picture.

Key elements are to use relative layout and to use 'to right of [the picture's id]' in the xml you use.

You can use this tutorial.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-relative-layouts/

Answer (score 3):

ok
then put `imageview` left side and put checkbox right side 
if you would like to make dynamic then one option are available but it is quit different. like
[image]

```
<CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/checkBox1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon" android:text="CheckBox" android:layout_x="58dip"  android:layout_y="106dip"></CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

If by front you actually mean to the right (or left of) I think the simplest and most efficient way would be to use the `android:drawableRight` (or `android:drawableLeft`) attribute e.g.,

`android:drawableRight="@drawable/my_img"`

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/my_checkBox1"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/my_img"
    android:text="Option_Text">
</Checkbox>
```

This is efficient as it uses the same view.

Comment: That's probably the most elegant way to do that but it seems like this doesn't work on JB. The image overlaps the checkbox and not placed in the correct location. Any idea how to that on JB ?